# AttributeError at /reg/ 'UserOurRegistraion' object has no attribute 'save'.При попытке регистрации Веб проект на django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

При попытке регистрации выше написанная ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста

```
   from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile

class UserOurRegistration(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    username = forms.CharField(required=True, label="Логин")
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label="Пароль")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password']

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
```

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.contrib import messages
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from .forms import UserOurRegistration, UserUpdateForm
    
    def register(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = UserOurRegistration(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, f'Аккаунт {username} был создан, введите имя пользователя и пароль для авторизации')
                return redirect('user')
        else:
            form = UserOurRegistration()
        return render(request, 'users/registraion.html', {'form': form, 'title':'Регистрация пользователя'})
    
    @login_required
    def profile(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            update_user = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    
            if update_user.is_valid():
                update_user.save()
                messages.success(request, f'Ваш аккаунт был успешно обновлен')
                return redirect('profile')
        else:
            update_user = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
    
        data = {
            'update_user': update_user
        }
    
        return render(request, 'users/profile.html', data)
```

Comment: UserOurRegistraion не имеет save. Может у вас api не такое?

Comment: возможно. Как узнать ?

Comment: может вы просто забыли букву t в UserOurRegistraion?

Comment: да вы правы, но ошибка осталась name 'UserOurRegistration' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: посмотрите что в формах from .forms import UserOurRegistraion

Comment: да, я это исправил, но ошибка все еще осталась

Comment: я имею ввиду в модуль залезьте и посмотрите

Comment: Там все исправлено, мне кажется ошибка в самих формах views

Comment: не нашел save https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/

Comment: п о м о г л о ?